# Failure to resolve internal domain names

Tags: windows, dns, domain-name

I have two domains that are accessible just fine outside my network. However, within the network:

1. One fails to resolve if the "www" prefix is omitted, but resolves if it is included.
2. The other fails to resolve, regardless of the "www" prefix.

The error when attempting to access #1 is: `This site can't be reached. XXX's server DNS address could not be found. ... ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.`

We are using a Windows DNS server internally. What could the issue be? Our IT department is saying that this is a known issue with Microsoft DNS servers, that Microsoft doesn't play well without a fully qualified domain name, and that if you omit the "www," then Microsoft assumes the primary domain controller, which isn't a web server. Thanks in advance.

Comment: your IT department did not set up the internal DNS properly

Comment: @Keltari, thanks for your comment. Care to elaborate?